# Android Interstitial Ad not loading

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm trying to load interstitial ad on the tablet, with the test ad id. On output ad is not showing, but I'm getting the callback on "onAdLoaded".

This is my code:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.ad_activity);

 mPublisherInterstitialAd = new PublisherInterstitialAd(this);
 mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("/6499/example/interstitial");
 mPublisherInterstitialAd.loadAd(newPublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());

    mPublisherInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            Log.d("AD ","LOADED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

            Log.d("AD ","FAILED");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you just created advertise ?, any error on logcat ?

Comment: This is my log..

Comment: what kind of ad id is `/6499/example/interstitial`  ?,Use this ad id `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`

Comment: interstiatial ads take time to be ready. after what you did you need to call   mPublisherInterstitialAd.show(). see https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Comment: These are my logs 
Starting ad request. 
Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.m.<init>

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public void inrequestadd() {
    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("Your ID");
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: So, where's the difference with the code in the question??

Comment: @SiddharthPatel, agree

Comment: I guess he just calls it somewhere else, yet it still doesn't work, because he just created it and doesn't use debug version of the ad...

Comment: may be didn't called that method.

Comment: I already implemented the above function and I'm getting the callback also "onAdLoaded". But my issue is , it is not showing on the screen.

Comment: after load have call this `mInterstitial.show();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle this kind of code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initAds();
}

private void initAds() {
      MobileAds.initialize(this, "your app id");
      mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);                         
      mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("your ad unit ID"); 
      mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

      mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

      });
}
```

Also in the manifest file:

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="your app id"/>
```

Next, depending on the logic of your app, you would have something like:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
   mInterstitialAd.show();
} else {
   System.out.println("The interstitial wasn't loaded yet. Do some other action");
}
```